# How I do a select a limited number of rows with the same attribute?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of URLs and one attribute is the domain.

Supposing I have 100 URLs from Google, 100 from Facebook, 100 from Ebay and the same for others domains, but I want to retrieve the first 30 URLs from Google, 30 from Facebook, 30 from Ebay and 30 from the others limiting to a max of 500 URLs.

How I do this?

Comment: How many domains you have in that table ? If more than 16, then how query should behave ?

Comment: Yes, a lot more than 16. If selecting 30 per domain exceed the max limit, stop getting more URLs. Example: if the limit was 70, get 30 from Google, 30 from Facebook,10 from Ebay and no one from the others.

Comment: And what domains should have preference? How is that determined?

Comment: The preference is not important. Only that it gives me 30 from each domain until reach the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following SQL resolves my case, but the urls are out of order because the row_number don't follow the orders. I think this SQL need some improvement.

```
SELECT url,row_number FROM(
     SELECT url,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY domain) FROM website
     WHERE domain IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM link)  
) AS links 
WHERE row_number <= 10
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: You could write `PARTITION BY domain ORDER BY ctid` or specify other column for ordering. Anyway, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT url FROM link WHERE domain='Google' LIMIT 30
UNION
SELECT url FROM link WHERE domain='Facebook' LIMIT 30
UNION
SELECT ...
```

etc.

Comment: I would suggest adding `SELECT 'Google', url....SELECT 'Facebook', url...` so he can tell which was from where.

Comment: But then can you put `LIMIT 70` at the end of all that?

Comment: You can wrap the unions in another SELECT, and then limit it, if that's what is needed

Comment: @duduamar: AFAIK you can't use LIMIT clause within UNION like that (syntax error). See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html

Comment: @Grzegorz I think you're right; so -1 here since it won't actually work.

Comment: Didn't know about that... is it only in PostgreSQL, or all SQL databases?

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can use `UNION` clause with multiple single limits, but you need to use parentheses `(SELECT url FROM ..)`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution in PL/pgSQL based. I found a better way, that you don't need additional temporary table (using `INSERT` to that table in function's body), that is you can use that function to get result directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getURLs(singleLimit integer, totalLimit integer)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    dom text;
    nrOfDomains integer;
    i integer;
    lim integer;
    remainder integer;
BEGIN
    nrOfDomains := totalLimit/singleLimit; -- integer division (truncate)
    remainder := totalLimit%singleLimit;

    IF remainder <> 0 THEN
        nrOfDomains := nrOfDomains + 1;
    END IF;

    i := 1;
    FOR dom IN SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM website LIMIT nrOfDomains
    LOOP
        IF i = nrOfDomains AND remainder <> 0 THEN
            lim := remainder;
        ELSE
            lim := singleLimit;
        END IF;

        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM website WHERE domain = dom LIMIT lim;

        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Here is some test-drive:

```
postgres=> CREATE TABLE website(url text, domain text);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=> INSERT INTO website
    SELECT 'http://' || d.column1  ||'/' || n, d.column1
    FROM generate_series(1, 100) n CROSS JOIN
    (VALUES ('google'), ('facebook'), ('ebay')) d;
INSERT 0 300

postgres=> SELECT * FROM getURLs(10, 25) website(url text, domain text);
```

Result:

```
        url         |  domain
--------------------+----------
 http://google/1    | google
 http://google/2    | google
 http://google/3    | google
 http://google/4    | google
 http://google/5    | google
 http://google/6    | google
 http://google/7    | google
 http://google/8    | google
 http://google/9    | google
 http://google/10   | google
 http://facebook/1  | facebook
 http://facebook/2  | facebook
 http://facebook/3  | facebook
 http://facebook/4  | facebook
 http://facebook/5  | facebook
 http://facebook/6  | facebook
 http://facebook/7  | facebook
 http://facebook/8  | facebook
 http://facebook/9  | facebook
 http://facebook/10 | facebook
 http://ebay/1      | ebay
 http://ebay/2      | ebay
 http://ebay/3      | ebay
 http://ebay/4      | ebay
 http://ebay/5      | ebay
(25 rows)
```

Comment: I understand why you wrote `IF 500%30 <> 0` but it made me chuckle nonetheless. :)

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that if you want the domains to be randomly ordered you could use `FOR d IN SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM website LIMIT nrOfDomains ORDER BY RAND()`, or if you want them to be ordered in some other way that is the spot to do it.

Comment: @Chris Cunningham: Yes, I changed that `500%30` to be more general `totalLimit%singleLimit`.